# Triggering inputs on page: radio type not working

Tags: jquery, triggers, radio-button

I'm trying to trigger all the change events for inputs on a page of various types so that the various effects they have occur on page load, if, say a box is checked or a drop down is a certain value.

I'm using the following:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("select").trigger('change');
 $("input").trigger('change');     
});
```

Which works great for the check boxes and drop downs, the radios seem to refuse to trigger.

The radios on question all have events bound to change by the following code (for example):

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
    $("input[name$='q_4']").change(function(){
        if(this.value == 'Yes') {
              $('#qu_5').removeClass('hide');
        } else {
             $('#qu_5').addClass('hide');
        }
    });             
});
```

In trying to work out why, I've tried triggering radios by type:

```
$("input[type='radio']").trigger('change');
```

By specific id of the radio I want to trigger:

```
 $("#id_of_checked_radio").trigger('change');
```

By name of radio group:

```
$("input[name='radio_group']").trigger('change');
```

The handler is defined for the radio inputs in the same place as the other input types, which work fine so I'm fairly sure it's not the order of my code, is there something about radio buttons which is different to trigger?

Comment: has a change event been bound to the radio button?

Comment: @vishakvkt Yes - and it works well when the page is loaded (i.e. if user clicks on radio buttons it behaves as expected)